# waitpid for parent-child signalling

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

I have a parent and a child process communicating through a pipe. Parent writes and child reads. Moreover, once the child has finished reading, it does some processing on the data that has been read. 
I need to ensure that the parent waits until the child has finished with its processing with this data(not terminate).

All I need is a simple wait/signal mechanism between parent and child.

I believe parent, after it has done writing, can call  waitpid(child_process_id, &status, flag). But I am not sure how can child signal for its change of state, and what flag should the parent wait on.

Will appreciate any pointer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom signal. In that case, the child uses `getppid()` to get its parent process and sends it that signal via `kill`. In the meanwhile the parent sets a signal handler for the specific signal (via `signal`) and waits using `waitpid`. As `waitpid` is interruptible, the parent will be notified that child has finished its processing, and will also stops waiting if child dies without sending it signal for any reason.

Alternatively, just setup a second pipe where parent reads and child writes. The parent simply reads its pipe end. The child writes a short message (OK or DONE) to notify its parent that its processing is finished and closes the the pipe. It parent gets the message, it knows that the processing was correct, if the pipe is closed with no message, it knows that something has gone wrong. IMHO, this is simpler to setup.